# Place array/multiselect data in modal after successful Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call which returns an employee Name and Id. These are an array which I wish to make available in a multiselect box in a Modal pop up. I also wish to show selected value if possible?

My console log shows:

```
Object {employees: Object}
employees:Object
data: Array(2)
0: Object
id: 1
name: "Sam Test 1"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
id: 2
name: "Joe Test 2"
__proto__: Object
```

My ajax call is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editApptModal-button').click(function() {
    var appointmentID = $(this).attr('data-appointmentID');
    console.log(appointmentID);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      method: 'get',
      url: '/ajax',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response.employees.data, function(key, value) {
          $('select').append($("<option/>", {
            value: key,
            text: value
          }));
        });

        $('#editApptModal').modal('show');
      },
      error: function(response) {
        alert('Could not displaying data' + response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

So what do I need to do here to place id in option value and name in option text?

```
$.each(response.employee.data, function(key, value) {
  $('select').append($("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
  }));
});
```

Update
With `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));`:

```
{
    "employees": {
        "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sam Test 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Joe Test 2"
        }]
    }
}
```

Select box

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="employees" class="form-control search-select">    
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the result if you add: `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` in your code?

Comment: i have added the response from JSON.stringify.

Comment: I've update my answer with a demo where you can see how to show the selected values in multiselect box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `response.employee.data` to `response.employees.data`.

You can use the `value` property to get the values of the object.

```js
(function() {
  var data = {
    "employees": {
      "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sam Test 1"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Joe Test 2"
      }]
    }
  };
  $.each(data.employees.data, function(key, value) {
    $('select').append($("<option/>", {
      value: value.id,
      text: value.name
    }));
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="employees" class="form-control search-select">    
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

If don't need to have an empty option, remove the default option in your html.
And this is the way to show the selected values.

```js
(function() {
  var data = {
    "employees": {
      "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sam Test 1"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Joe Test 2"
      }]
    }
  };
  $.each(data.employees.data, function(key, value) {
    $('select').append($("<option/>", {
      value: value.id,
      text: value.name
    }));
  });

  $("select[name=employees]").on("change", function() {
    $("#result").html("Selected values: " + $(this).val().join("\n"));
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="employees" class="form-control search-select">
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**With jQuery.select2:** Showing the selected data with jQuery.select2.

```js
(function() {
  var data = {
    "employees": {
      "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sam Test 1"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Joe Test 2"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Joe Test 3"
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Joe Test 4"
      }]
    }
  };
  $.each(data.employees.data, function(key, value) {
    $('select').append($("<option/>", {
      value: value.id,
      text: value.name
    }));
  });
  $("select[name=employees]").val(data.employees.data.map(function(x) {
    return x.id;
  })); // Set the selected data before show it.
  $('select').select2();
})();
```

```css
select[name=employees] {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select name="employees" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Comment: If I am using select2 search drop down any idea how I can set the results in the input section as default? https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple

Comment: looks good. I was miles off looking at what I can do after page loads. If values [1 , 2] are dynamic would is still work ?

Comment: Yes. The important thing here is that when you have a multiple select the `values `that are saved are arrays. **e.g.:** Array of numbers: `[1,2,3]`. Array of strings: `["num1", "num2", "num3"]`.

Comment: I am trying to implement your snippet. my value are coming for Ajax call.   $("select[name=employees]").val(data.employees.data);

Comment: $("select[name=employees]").val([0, 1]) The 0 prints the first result, but nothing for the second.

Comment: Does the select multiple has the `1` value in the option? Please update your answer with your current code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148256/discussion-between-eden-webstudio-and-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez).

Comment: @EdenWebStudio I've updated my answer with dynamic result. See `$("select[name=employees]").val(data.employees.data.map(function(x) {
    return x.id;
  }));`.

Comment: This has worked finally! Thanks for your help and patience! js, jquery are not my strongest points or even a real skill for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like this:

```
$.each(response.employees.data, function(key, value) {
    $('select').append($("<option>", {
     value: value.id,
     text: value.name
       }));
   });
```

Comment: @EdenWebStudio it is working for me with `response` given above, can you check again and confirm?

Comment: fixed id thing. my typo mistake but now the select box comes up blank....Do I need to put anything in the <select> tags?

Comment: @EdenWebStudio not sure what is the problem here, but maybe the extra option you have added to select with empty string `<option value=""> </option>` try removing this.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Only thing is when I close the modal and open it again without page refresh, it repeats the names.